# <footer> is rendering over main React content, but CSS is working fine in snippet

Tags: css, reactjs

So I had this CSS in an app that I was working on before I decided to start using React. Basically what it does is simple: if there isn't enough "main" content on a page, the footer will appear at the bottom of the window; if there is enough "main" content to necessitate scrolling, it will push the footer to the end of the content.

**This is not a `position: fixed`. I don't want the footer to always be at the bottom of the screen taking up view port space.**

Since migrating to React it does not work. It is almost like the `<Footer />` component ignores all of the other "main" content components and I'm not sure how to resolve that.

It renders the `<Footer />` at the bottom of the window, but it scrolls with the screen. For example, it renders at bottom, the "main" content extends past it, you scroll down to view content and the footer will scroll with the window and sit over the content.

Here is a picture to hopefully explain it better.

[image: footer]

To reiterate, **it should not be fixed to the bottom of the window.** Please see the snippets for a demonstration. **Really it just seems like the footer in React doesn't know there is content and somehow needs to be made aware of it.**

Here is how I have the `app.js` setup:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <div>
            <div className='container'>
                <Navigation />
            </div>
            <div className='custom-container'>
                <div className='container'>
                    <App />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/home' component={protectedRoute(Home)} />
                        <Route exact path='/help' component={protectedRoute(Help)} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/username' component={RecoverUsername} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/new_account' component={NewAccount} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/password' component={ResetPassword} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/signout' component={Signout} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/signin' component={Signin} />

                        <Route exact path='/auth/security_questions/f=:f&i=:id&k=:key' component={SecurityQuestions} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/set_password/f=:f&i=:id&k=:key' component={SetPassword} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/setup_user/f=:f&i=:id&k=:key' component={SetupUser} />
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Signin} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='gap'></div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

**Here snippets showing it in action when it actually works:**

This snippet shows how it places the footer at the bottom of the window when there is very little content.

```css
body, html {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100vh;

}

footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-top: 1px solid #d3e0e9;
 overflow: auto;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;

 p {
  margin: -1px;
 }
}

#gap {
 padding: 58px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>

<p>Content</p>


<div id="gap">
</div>

<footer class="footer">
 <div class="container">
  <p>footer</p>
 </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the snippet with more content added showing how it pushes the footer past the bottom of the screen and below content.

```css
body, html {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100vh;

}

footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-top: 1px solid #d3e0e9;
 overflow: auto;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;

 p {
  margin: -1px;
 }
}

#gap {
 padding: 58px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>

<p>Content</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<p>Content</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<p>Content</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<p>Content</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="gap">
</div>

<footer class="footer">
 <div class="container">
  <p>footer</p>
 </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**So how can I get this to render properly in React?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <div class="app">
            <div className='container'>
                <Navigation />
            </div>
            <div className='custom-container'>
                <div className='container'>
                    <App />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/home' component={protectedRoute(Home)} />
                        <Route exact path='/help' component={protectedRoute(Help)} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/username' component={RecoverUsername} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/new_account' component={NewAccount} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/password' component={ResetPassword} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/signout' component={Signout} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/signin' component={Signin} />

                        <Route exact path='/auth/security_questions/f=:f&i=:id&k=:key' component={SecurityQuestions} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/set_password/f=:f&i=:id&k=:key' component={SetPassword} />
                        <Route exact path='/auth/setup_user/f=:f&i=:id&k=:key' component={SetupUser} />
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Signin} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='gap'></div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, 
html,
.app {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;   
}
```

body and html are no longer the root elements of your app content, add `app` class to the root div of app content and same css and it should work :D

Comment: I was extremely hopefully, but unfortunately the issue is still persisting.

Comment: do you have a git repo or something where I can check the code?

Comment: I think I spoke too soon. I started moving the `.container` and `.custom-container` classes out of the `index.js` (because I just hated the way it looked) and moved them into their respective components. So the ones that were wrapped around `<App />` I moved into the `app.js` and it looks like the footer is now rendering below the content. My formatting is messed up in other ways now, but at least that footer seems to be fixed.